# data frame operations in R

Tags: r

This may be a very simple question but can someone explain to me how the below operations work.

- I was told that the square bracket operator always return objects of
  the same type. Therefore dataframe[1] (data frame object) will return
  a data frame.
- However, I was also told that objects are automatically coerced to
  the lowest dimension so numeric.vector[1] will return a numeric
  value not a vector of length 1. Why doesn't it work for data
  frames?
- Also, dataframe[1, ] will return the same results as
  dataframe[1]. However, dataframe[,1] will return me a vector (not 
  a dataframe) of the first row but I'm also using a single bracket.

Comment: 1) Perhaps for the specific example but wrong as a general rule; 2) What is the difference between a numeric value and a vector of length 1?; (In R there is no difference). 3a) Wrong. 3b) also wrong. The "[" operator/function is generic so the action depends on the type of argument given to it.

Comment: Check out hadley's section on subsetting: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, data frames are a special type of list.  Here is an explanation of the various operations you listed:

```
# data frame 'dataframe'

dataframe[1] # a data frame containing only the first column
dataframe[1, ] # a one-row dataframe containing only the first row
dataframe[, 1] # a vector created from the first column
```

I'm not sure what you are referring to with numeric.vector[1], but the last example you gave (`dataframe[, 1]`) returns a vector.